# Переопределение переменной с конвейром bash

Tags: bash

Здравствуйте. Только-только начал разбираться с bash.

Нужно построчно прочесть файл, где каждая строка на кирилице, и при помощи idn преобразовать в punycode.

Пытаюсь так, но не получается.

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line"  ]]; do
    newline = $line | idn 
    echo "$newline"
done < "$1"
```

***ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ***

Важно именно переопределить переменную, т.к. она будет использоваться в скрипте и дальше.

Comment: Как выглядят строчки в файле?

Comment: правительство.рф, госдума.рф и т.д.

Comment: так и написано — через запятую?

Comment: Может просто не писать на языке, который для этого прямо не предназначен? Кстати, почему бы не попробовать `idn -e < $file` ?

Answer (score 1):

если я правильно понял логику написанного вами (скажем так, несколько эзотерическую), то вы хотите что-то наподобие:

```
newline = $(echo $line | idn)
```

Comment: В чём эзотеричность ? В том, что нужно кириллическое название привести в punycode ? Или в том, что файл нужно читать построчно ?

Comment: в том, что написано между while и do

Comment: А документацию прочитать не судьба? Весь этот огород не нужен, можно просто запустить `idn -e < $file` (whatever *$file* is)